# Browser support for Angular material

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, flexbox, angularjs-material

I want to use Angular Material for my next projects. https://material.angularjs.org

I didn't find any documentation about which browsers it supports.
Anyone knows how it internally works and what to expect?

From what I understand `flex` css attribute, for example not supported by IE<10.
Do you know if Angular material, has any fallback design for using without the `flex` css?

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/726

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://github.com/angular/material):

> Please note that using Angular Material requires the use of Angular
>   1.3.x or higher. Angular Material is targeted for all browsers with versions n-1; where n is the current browser version.

Also you can find several polyfill to extend the Browser's compatibility reading in their official forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ngmaterial

Answer (score 10):

As Angular Material uses CSS3 [Flexbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/), supported browsers are:

- **IE 11+**,
- **Chrome**,
- **Safari**,
- **Firefox**,
- **Android 4.2+** and
- **iOS 8+**.

More details can be found at [angularjs.blogspot.co.uk](http://angularjs.blogspot.co.uk/2015/12/angular-material-10-now-available.html).